# Após o método de validação ser true, como cancelar o envio dos dados ao banco?

Tags: java, jdbc

Tenho a aplicação ja feita. A classe `Produto`, `ProdutoDAO` e um método `validaProdutoPorDescricao()`

```
JButton btnCadastrarProduto = new JButton("Cadastrar");
        btnCadastrarProduto.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                Produto prod = new Produto();
                prod.setDescricao(campoDescricao.getText());
                /*if (!prod.validaProdutoPorDescricao(prod))
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Produto com nome inválido");*/

                prod.setSaldoEstoque(Integer.parseInt(campoSaldoEstoque.getText()));
                prod.setPrecoCompra(Float.parseFloat(campoPrecoDeCompra.getText()));
                prod.setPrecoVenda(Float.parseFloat(campoPrecoDeVenda.getText()));

                ProdutoDAO prodao = new ProdutoDAO(Database.getConnection());
                prodao.registra(prod);

                campoDescricao.setText("");
                campoSaldoEstoque.setText("");
                campoPrecoDeCompra.setText("");
                campoPrecoDeVenda.setText("");

                // TODO FAZER AÇÃO DO BOTÃO CADASTRAR
            }
        });
        btnCadastrarProduto.setBounds(231, 200, 135, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnCadastrarProduto);
```

A parte comentada é onde faço um teste para chamar o método e verificar o argumento passado para ele. O método funciona, porém queria fazer com que, caso o método seja chamado, interromper os dados passados no formulário e cancelar o envio, pois mesmo o método sendo chamado os dados estão indo para o banco.

Comment: Alterei, coloquei o código!
Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente envolver a lógica com um `else`:

```
JButton btnCadastrarProduto = new JButton("Cadastrar");
        btnCadastrarProduto.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                Produto prod = new Produto();
                prod.setDescricao(campoDescricao.getText());

                if (!prod.validaProdutoPorDescricao(prod)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Produto com nome inválido");
               } else {

                prod.setSaldoEstoque(Integer.parseInt(campoSaldoEstoque.getText()));
                prod.setPrecoCompra(Float.parseFloat(campoPrecoDeCompra.getText()));
                prod.setPrecoVenda(Float.parseFloat(campoPrecoDeVenda.getText()));

                ProdutoDAO prodao = new ProdutoDAO(Database.getConnection());
                prodao.registra(prod);

                campoDescricao.setText("");
                campoSaldoEstoque.setText("");
                campoPrecoDeCompra.setText("");
                campoPrecoDeVenda.setText("");
                }
                // TODO FAZER AÇÃO DO BOTÃO CADASTRAR
            }
        });
        btnCadastrarProduto.setBounds(231, 200, 135, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnCadastrarProduto);
```

Comment: Irei ver, mas esse lance de setAutoCommit(), será que é ideal usar?

Comment: @RenanNarciso não faço ideia do que você está falando.

Comment: Método usado no jdbc para poder colocar o commit automatico ou não automático, mas quando eu estiver próximo do computador irei ver o que vc disse ali sobre por a lógica dentro do `else`

Comment: Valeu @diegofm, consegui solucionar colocando um `else`